# How to make a div float to a center of a container, along dynamic elements that will be added according to user's input

Tags: html, vb.net, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a div float to the center of it's container div, but the thing is that the user may decide to add from 1 up to 12 elements, so they must float in lines of 4. So, if the user adds only one element, this should float to the center of the container, if he/she adds two, they must float to the center of the container but next to each other. If the User adds 5 elements, the first four must float side by side (filling the width 100% of the container) and the fifth should be on the second line, at the center. This images show what I want to achieve:

**Image 1: One element**
[image: With one box]

User input: only one box that floats to center.

**Image 2: two elements**
[image: with two boxes]

The user selected two elements, so both of them float side of each other and to the center of the container div.

**Image 3: four elements**
[image: The first line is full]

The user selected four elements, so the first side is full, the 100% of the container div is filled by four boxes of 25% with each.

**Image 4: five elements**
[image: Five boxes]

If the user selects 5 elements, the fifth one shall float to the center of the container div, right below the first line of the other 4 boxes.

**With 6 boxes:**
[image]

**Seven boxes!**
[image]

So, at the end, I'll be adding some asp.net vb that will bring the desired boxes to a repeater control, according to some data stored in a SQL database, and bringing the desired controls through a stored procedure.

I've been trying different techniques, but none of them have solved my issue (margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block; etc...)

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider flexbox. Here are some alignment options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276 ...

Comment: @Michael_B That's just what I was looking for!!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a flexbox solution:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"><span>1</span></div>
    <div class="box box2"><span>2</span></div>
    <div class="box box3"><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="box box4"><span>4</span></div>
    <div class="box box5"><span>5</span></div>
    <div class="box box6"><span>6</span></div>
    <div class="box box7"><span>7</span></div>
    <div class="box box8"><span>8</span></div>
    <div class="box box9"><span>9</span></div>
    <div class="box box10"><span>10</span></div>
    <div class="box box11"><span>11</span></div>
    <div class="box box12"><span>12</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html { height: 100%; }

body {     
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;    
    }

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lf7ufxk/1)

In the demo, try removing any number of divs. Remaining divs will always be centered.

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you, you really saved the day!